# BroadcastReceiver issue

Tags: java, android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver

BroadcastReceiver issue with android studio.

Comment: 2 questions 1=> is your receiver registered; 2=> how did you start your service?

Comment: I did a static registration inside the manifest, but I still don't understand what else I'm supposed to do. Do I also need to register within the MyReceiver class? In reference to your 2nd question, I use context.startService(i) in my code above to start the service. I am trying to log when the phone gets connected or disconnected from the charger, but I'm clearly doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register the broadcast receiver: `MyReceiver`

```
val batteryStatus: Intent? = IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED).let { ifilter ->
    context.registerReceiver(MyReceiver(), ifilter)
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Kotlin so this is slightly confusing. Where am I supposed to register the receiver? I statically registered in the Manifest but I'm having trouble figuring out what else I need to add to get the registration to work.

Comment: If you are targeting API 26+ (reqd for Play Store approval) registering broadcasts in manifest is not supported unless the broadcast is targeting your app. You can register it anywhere you have a `Context` such as Activity or Application